# Perform count function on columns and append string result to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello guys I would like to count rows in a dataset and append total counts to column names 
. Here is how my dataset looks like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([('Jorh Hospital','2017-03-15', 389.0,34, 32, 34),
                   ('Jorh Hospital','2018-04-20', np.nan,22, 5, 43),
                   ('Jorh Hospital','2018-05-20', np.nan,22, 5, 43),
                   ('Bugh Hospital','2019-02-16', 80.5,np.nan, 56, np.nan),
                   ('Bugh Hospital','2019-03-23', np.nan,89, 67, np.nan),
                  ('Bugh Hospital','2019-04-23', np.nan,89, 67, np.nan)],
                  columns=('Hosp_name','date', 'max_rec', 'reg_pp', 'disch_no', 'temp_rec'))
df
```

What I have tried is this  which I can only do per individual column. How can I do all columns at ones

```
df['max_rec'].count()
df['reg_pp'].count()
```

I dont want to do it individually like that, how can I perform count per columns and results be appended to column name like this final result

```
import pandas as pd
dff = pd.DataFrame([('Jorh Hospital','2017-03-15', 389.0,34, 32, 34),
                   ('orh Hospital','2018-04-20', np.nan,22, 5, 43),
                   ('Jorh Hospital','2018-05-20', np.nan,22, 5, 43),
                   ('Bugh Hospital','2019-02-16', 80.5,np.nan, 56, np.nan),
                   ('Bugeh Hospital','2019-03-23', np.nan,89, 67, np.nan),
                  ('ugh Hospital','2019-04-23', np.nan,89, 67, np.nan)],
                  columns=('Hosp_name','date', 'max_rec N=2', 'reg_pp N=5', 'disch_no N=6', 'temp_rec N=3'))
dff
```

Expected

```
dff = pd.DataFrame([('max_rec','50% (1)', '50%(1)'),
                   ('reg_pp','100%(0)', '50%(1)'),
                   ('disch_no','100%(0)', '100%(0)'),
                   ('temp_rec','100%(0)', '0')],
                  columns=('variables','Jorh Hospital (N=2)', 'Bugh Hospital (N=2)'))
dff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all columns without first 2 by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html), then create dictionary with joined values and pass to `rename`:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 2:].count()
d = dict(zip(s.index, s.index + ' N=' + s.astype(str)))
df = df.rename(columns=d)
print (df)
        Hosp_name        date  max_rec N=2  reg_pp N=5  disch_no N=6  \
0   Jorh Hospital  2017-03-15        389.0        34.0            32   
1    orh Hospital  2018-04-20          NaN        22.0             5   
2   Jorh Hospital  2018-05-20          NaN        22.0             5   
3   Bugh Hospital  2019-02-16         80.5         NaN            56   
4  Bugeh Hospital  2019-03-23          NaN        89.0            67   
5    ugh Hospital  2019-04-23          NaN        89.0            67   

   temp_rec N=3  
0          34.0  
1          43.0  
2          43.0  
3           NaN  
4           NaN  
5           NaN
```

EDIT:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 2:].count()
d = dict(zip(s.index, s.index + ' N=' + s.astype(str)))
df = df.iloc[:,2:].notna().groupby(df['Hosp_name']).mean().T.rename(d)
print (df)
Hosp_name     Bugeh Hospital  Bugh Hospital  Jorh Hospital  orh Hospital  \
max_rec N=2              0.0            1.0            0.5           0.0   
reg_pp N=5               1.0            0.0            1.0           1.0   
disch_no N=6             1.0            1.0            1.0           1.0   
temp_rec N=3             0.0            0.0            1.0           1.0   

Hosp_name     ugh Hospital  
max_rec N=2            0.0  
reg_pp N=5             1.0  
disch_no N=6           1.0  
temp_rec N=3           0.0
```

EDIT1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('Jorh Hospital','2017-03-15', 389.0,34, 32, 34),
                   ('Jorh Hospital','2018-04-20', np.nan,22, 5, 43),
                   ('Jorh Hospital','2018-05-20', np.nan,22, 5, 43),
                   ('Bugh Hospital','2019-02-16', 80.5,np.nan, 56, np.nan),
                   ('Bugh Hospital','2019-03-23', np.nan,89, 67, np.nan),
                  ('Bugh Hospital','2019-04-23', np.nan,89, 67, np.nan)],
                  columns=('Hosp_name','date', 'max_rec', 'reg_pp', 'disch_no', 'temp_rec'))

print (df)
       Hosp_name        date  max_rec  reg_pp  disch_no  temp_rec
0  Jorh Hospital  2017-03-15    389.0    34.0        32      34.0
1  Jorh Hospital  2018-04-20      NaN    22.0         5      43.0
2  Jorh Hospital  2018-05-20      NaN    22.0         5      43.0
3  Bugh Hospital  2019-02-16     80.5     NaN        56       NaN
4  Bugh Hospital  2019-03-23      NaN    89.0        67       NaN
5  Bugh Hospital  2019-04-23      NaN    89.0        67       NaN
```

---

```
df = (df.iloc[:,2:]
         .notna()
         .astype(int)
         .groupby(df['Hosp_name'])
        .agg(['sum', 'mean'])
        .stack(0))
print (df)
                            mean  sum
Hosp_name                            
Bugh Hospital disch_no  1.000000    3
              max_rec   0.333333    1
              reg_pp    0.666667    2
              temp_rec  0.000000    0
Jorh Hospital disch_no  1.000000    3
              max_rec   0.333333    1
              reg_pp    1.000000    3
              temp_rec  1.000000    3
```

---

```
a = df['mean'].mul(100).round(0).astype(int).astype(str) + '% '
b = '(' + df['sum'].astype(str) + ')' 

s = df['sum'].sum(level=0)
d = dict(zip(s.index, s.index + ' N=' + s.astype(str)))
print (d)
{'Bugh Hospital': 'Bugh Hospital N=6', 'Jorh Hospital': 'Jorh Hospital N=10'}

df = a.add(b).unstack(0).rename(columns=d)
print (df)
Hosp_name Bugh Hospital N=6 Jorh Hospital N=10
disch_no           100% (3)           100% (3)
max_rec             33% (1)            33% (1)
reg_pp              67% (2)           100% (3)
temp_rec             0% (0)           100% (3)
```

Comment: A Kindly could you modify your code to groupby hospital_name so that hospital name can be columns the append counts to it

Comment: I have this column that groups the rows by hospital name ```df.iloc[:,2:].notna().groupby(df['Hosp_name']).mean().T```, you can run it to see the expected dataframe but before doing mean I want to have counts first

Comment: Your edited answer is exactly what I want but could you remove the count number from index so that it be appended to hospital name, counts be per hospital

Comment: I have edited the dataframe to only have two hospitals to group

Comment: Have added a table  at the end of  how expected results should look like after counting and performing mean. so counts is for values per hospital then mean is to get the number of NANs in percentage

Comment: the output you are getting is correct, whatever I have added to the quiz is just to give a picture of how I want it to be.

Comment: @LivingstoneM - Answer was edited, please check if it is what you need. Most helpfull should be create expected output from last sample data, if need something different. thanks.